# Openshift in docker container runs on port 443, but port not published

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

I have Openshift running in docker.
No ports are explicitly published from any open shift container.

But anyway - the application is reachable from host, on port 8443. 
How is that possible?

[image]

[image]

The cluster was started, using an OpenShift binary "oc". The command was `oc cluster up`
So I do not know, which parameters were passed to docker.

But here I found a howto, about starting OpenShift directly, and those parameters are used:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --name "origin" \
        --privileged --pid=host --net=host \
        -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:rw \
        -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw \
        -v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:rslave \ 
        openshift/origin start
```

Comment: Do you use `--network=host` ?

Comment: How did you start it? Is this using ``oc cluster up``? It is normal that it will expose port 8443 for accessing the OpenShift web console. The ``oc cluster up`` tool will expose the containers on the appropriate ports. The ``EXPOSE`` statements in images only really serve as documentation, as you are still dependent on whatever runs the container to say what is really exposed and what it maps to externally.

Comment: I extended the article with details about how the cluster was started. `oc cluster up` was used. And I was not aware, that a container may use ports (here 8443), without stating that it exposes the ports.

Comment: In this case, as suggested by @Henry it is likely because ``--net=host`` is used which may mean that the container can grab what ports it need without them needing to be declared at all.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by @Henry it is likely because `--net=host` is used which may mean that the container can grab what ports it need without them needing to be declared at all